# SELECT DISTINCT values after JOIN (asp classic)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, asp-classic, distinct

I'm trying to select distinct(tr.item_id) from the table `term_relationships`. I want to avoid listing a post twice if it's related to many tags.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

The query:

```
tag_inject = "tr.taxonomy_id = 94 or tr.taxonomy_id = 92 or tr.taxonomy_id = 93"

SELECT * FROM term_relationships tr" + _
" INNER JOIN term_taxonomy tax ON tr.taxonomy_id = tax.taxonomy_id" + _
" INNER JOIN post po ON tr.item_id = po.post_id" + _
" where tr.cpa_id = " & cpa_id & " and (" & tag_inject & ")" + _
" and po.cpa_id = " & cpa_id & " and po.post_status = 1" + _
" order by po.post_start_date desc limit " & amount_1
```

---

### I answer here, since the comments field are to small and I didn't want to wait for 6 hours

Thanks guys,

I was trying to do the whole thing in one query, but I don't think that is possible when I need the item_id distinct?

So I decided to get the post data with a sub query, after getting the distinct items list.

Kind of like this:

```
sql_tags = "SELECT distinct tr.item_id" + _
" FROM term_relationships tr" + _
" INNER JOIN term_taxonomy tax ON tr.taxonomy_id = tax.taxonomy_id" + _
" INNER JOIN post po ON tr.item_id = po.post_id" + _
" where tr.cpa_id = " & clng(cpa_id) & " and (" & tag_inject & ")" + _
" and po.cpa_id = " & clng(cpa_id) & " and po.post_status = 1" + _
" order by po.post_start_date desc limit " & clng(content_amount_1)
set rs_plist = conn.execute(sql_tags)
```

And then..

```
while not rs_plist.eof 

get_item_id = rs_plist("item_id")

sql = "select rec_id, post_id, post_title, post_line_desc, post_image_1, post_image_1_width from " & app_database & ".post" + _
" where cpa_id = " & clng(cpa_id) & " and post_id = " & get_item_id
set rs_post = conn.execute(sql)
```

..and so on..

Is there a better alternative, or is this the way to do it?

Comment: use the `select distinct` clause

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sql Query for Selecting Distinct Record . 
In case you want output as only distinct term_id from table term_relationships you can write following Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT term_id FROM term_relationships
```

or

```
SELECT term_id FROM term_relationships GROUP BY term_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the list of field you want to retrieve, you cannot use the `DISTINCT` keyword with `*`.

You should use something like this to get the unique post_id

```
tag_inject = "tr.taxonomy_id = 94 or tr.taxonomy_id = 92 or tr.taxonomy_id = 93"

SELECT DISTINCT po.post_id FROM term_relationships tr" + _
" INNER JOIN term_taxonomy tax ON tr.taxonomy_id = tax.taxonomy_id" + _
" INNER JOIN post po ON tr.item_id = po.post_id" + _
" where tr.cpa_id = " & cpa_id & " and (" & tag_inject & ")" + _
" and po.cpa_id = " & cpa_id & " and po.post_status = 1" + _
" order by po.post_start_date desc limit " & amount_1
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I know. Just wanted to give you the short version of the query, so you could get a clue of what I was trying to do. I've updated my question with my "solution" and I was wondering if that's the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your field names - using * is technically bad practice.  To this end, you'll want to remove the field that specifies your tag names and only include them in your `WHERE` clause.  That way `DISTINCT` will actually work.

Comment: I know. Just wanted to give you the short version of the query, so you could get a clue of what I was trying to do :)